# Is there a way to claim unused Facebook app namespaces?

Tags: facebook, namespaces

I'm working on building a new app. However, pretty much every namespace I've thought of that would be appropriate for my app is taken. When I go to see what already exists that uses the name, I usually either get a "page not found" error or an app that is broken. It seems likely that most of these have either never been used, or have been abandoned by the developer for a long time.

Does Facebook have some sort of process to free up or allow users to claim these unused namespaces? Or are they stuck unless the developer decides to give up the name?

Thanks!

Comment: Better asked on [Facebook Developers Group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/)